# Format a time with Ruby (on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
t = Time.now
d = 10.minutes.from_now
```

Using these two variables, how do I output a timer like `00:10:00`?

As `d` counts down, the timer would show `00:09:59`, `00:09:58`, etc.

**Note:** I'd formatting uses Rails `datetime` `format` method somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up working best for me:

```
def timer(end_time)
  Time.zone.at(end_time-Time.now).strftime("%R:%S")
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that this should do what you want.

```
def formatted_duration time_in_seconds
  Time.at(time_in_seconds).gmtime.strftime('%R:%S')
end

t = Time.now
d = t+ 10.minutes #10.minutes.from_now 
puts formatted_duration(d.to_i - t.to_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be faster:

```
def timer(end_time)
  d = (end_time - Time.now).to_i
  return "#{(d/60)%60}:#{d%60}"
end
```

No in your irb console:

```
>> t = Time.now + 15.minutes
=> Thu Mar 18 11:32:58 -0700 2010
>> timer(t)
=> "14:54"
>> timer(t)
=> "14:52"
>> timer(t)
=> "14:50"
```

Comment: I like where this is going but it needs to display seconds too!