# How would I format a time string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's the string I've got: `00:03:30.877615`

That's hours, minutes and seconds.

What I want to do is format that same string as: `3:30`

I basically want minutes (without the leading zero) and whole seconds.

The string will mostly be the same, but the length of the decimal places could change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format a time with Ruby (on Rails)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466741/format-a-time-with-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535004/date-with-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here. If you know your starting string is always going to be the same length/structure you could do a simple string transform:

```
start_time = '00:03:30.877615'
mins_and_secs = start_time[3..7]
mins_and_secs = mins_and_secs[1..-1] if mins_and_secs[0] == '0'
```

This is going to be the fastest option. If you're expecting more variation you could actually create a [Time object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-c-new) and then use [#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime).

Comment: The string will mostly be the same, but the length of the decimal places could change.

Comment: That won't matter, this solution ignores everything after the decimal point.

Comment: Matt, forgot to mention, I'm using Ruby 1.8.7...and I think that's screwing up that last line.

Comment: Ah yeah, strings are now arrays of characters instead of ints in 1.9, use this instead: mins_and_secs = mins_and_secs[1..-1] if mins_and_secs[0,1] == '0'

Answer (score 2):

The "-" takes out the leading zero in the minutes.

```
>> require 'time'
=> []
>> t = Time.parse('00:03:30.877615')
=> 2012-01-12 00:03:30 -0800
>> t.strftime("%-m:%S")
=> "1:30"
```

Answer (score 0):

can you rely on that time format?  if so, I might just use a regular expression and pull out the bits I want:

```
reg = /\d\d:(\d\d):(\d\d).*/
if m = reg.match(s)
  "#{ m[1].to_i }:#{ m[2] }"
end
```

Comment: This will work, but simple string manipulation will be much faster. Just depends on whether you're in a context where that matters.